# How to refresh a part of the page view without refreshing the entire page in angular on a click event?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, angular2-template, angular2-changedetection

I am building a chat application using Angular. I have two components for the chat. One for each user. I am using a radio button component which creates a new message as radio button. The user selects an option. Once the user clicks on submit button the radio button message is edited and a new message is printed with the option selected by the user.

You can see the demonstration in the plunker below. If user1 creates the radio message and submits the option in the same view, it works as expected. But if user1 creates the radio message and user2 submits the option, then the radio button message is not edited but only generates a new message with the option selected.

The problem I am facing here is that I am unable to refresh the view on the click event. This will display the edited radio button message by removing the options to select.

There is an API available in Angular: ChangeDetection.
It goes something like this: [ANGULAR CHANGE DETECTION](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

```js
edit(message: Message): void {
        let result = JSON.stringify(message);
        if (!result) {
            return;
        }
        this.appService.update(this.message)
            .then(() => {
                return null;
            });
    }
```

But I am unable to use this API on click event.

Plunker for the same is attached: [Angular chat application](https://plnkr.co/edit/wYiXu7?p=info)

Is there any other way or work around to get this working?
Feel free to fork the plunker code and edit if needed.

Comment: Try to create two radio components and change radio. You will see that you are doing something wrong. You do not need `AppService.setMessage` and `AppService.getMessage` because this way you manipulate one object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `setMessage` and `getMessage` methods from AppService.

By using these methods you hold object in shared service. And as object and  array are mutable you will get a lot of problem with such implementation.

I would use `@Input` property for Radio component

**app.component.html home.component.html**

```
<mm-radio-message [message]="message" ...></mm-radio-message>
```

**radio.component.ts**

```
@Input() message: Message;
```

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CNLuA3?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have spent almost a week to figure this out. It solved the issue I was facing. By the way, what kind of problems you were talking about with the implementation I had done?

Comment: You won't be able to create several radio component with your implementation when you have setMessage getMessage. You will change only one the same object for all of radio components

Comment: Sure. That would be a problem. I get it now. Thanks again.